# Ignore .ssh/rc file?

Tags: ssh

I have a remote server that has a ~/.ssh/rc file. Every time I ssh into that server, it runs that file before it drops me into a remote shell. Normally this is what I want. Occasionally I do not want this.

Is there an option I can give when I ssh so that it will not execute ~/.ssh/rc?

Comment: Could you give more information about the motivations? The user rc files, in general, are expected to override the default rc files and be evaluated at the beginning of a program run.

Comment: Do you not want to run a shell at all, or just not execute `~/.ssh/rc`?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this from the client. It's a security feature: the `~/.ssh/rc` file may do things that the client must not be able to bypass (although that's not a common use).

The most obvious way to bypass whatever `~/.ssh/rc` does is to wrap it in code that depends on an environment variable, and to allow the client to pass this environment variable to the server (`AcceptEnv` directive in `/etc/sshd_config`).

Another way to do it from the server side is to [use a key with the `no-user-rc` parameter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/458451).

Answer (score 2):

The only way that I can see, after a brief scanning of the `ssh` and `sshd` manuals, for this file to *not* be executed through a change in the SSH *client* is by using a separate key to authenticate with the host.

The execution of `~/.ssh/rc` may be disabled by setting the option `no-user-rc` in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file for the specific keys that a user may use.

The file may ordinarily look like this:

```
ssh-ed25519 AAAASOMEKEYSIGNATUREHERE myself@somehost
```

This may be supplemented with options described in the `sshd` manual:

```
no-user-rc ssh-ed25519 AAAASOMEKEYSIGNATUREHERE myself@somehost
```

And then another, different, key may be added for when the `rc` file should be executed:

```
no-user-rc ssh-ed25519 AAAASOMEKEYSIGNATUREHERE myself@somehost
ssh-ed25519 AAAASOMEDIFFERENTKEYSIGNATUREHERE myself@somehost
```

Locally, you would then connect with separate keys depending on whether you'd wanted to execute the `rc` file or not, possibly by using the following configuration in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host myhost
    Hostname theremote.host
    User myself
    IdentityFile %d/.ssh/id_ed25519

Host myhost-norc
    Hostname theremote.host
    User myself
    IdentityFile %d/.ssh/id_ed25519-norc
```

Where the signature for the key in `~/.ssh/id_ed25519-norc` would match the `no-user-rc` key signature.

This seems rather involved though, but I  honestly couldn't find any other way of avoiding executing the `rc` file at all.  Another option would be, [as Gilles suggests](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/458454/116858), to let the `rc` file bypass whatever it is doing based on some environment variable, and instead call `/etc/ssh/sshrc` as would ordinarily be done if the `rc` file did not exist (the `sshd` manual say that if `/etc/ssh/sshrc` also does not exists, then `xauth` is used, see the `sshd` manual for further info).