# how to distinguish ssh from scp in ~/.ssh/rc?

Tags: ssh, scp, openssh, rc, banner

I'd like to launch `neofetch` (a small utility that displays a banner) each time I log into a remote server via OpenSSH. So, I just added `/usr/bin/neofetch` into my `~/.ssh/rc` file, and it works fine.
The problem is that `~/.ssh/rc` is also parsed when I `scp` into the server. A complete `scp` command works just fine, there is however a problem when I try to use the autocomplete feature of `scp`, when I type `<Tab><Tab>` so it displays the files/folders available on the remote server, example :

```
$ scp remote-host:/t <TAB><TAB>
\\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\`\\\"\\\"\\\"\\\  
\\\ \\\$\\\$\\\:\\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\$\\\$.\\\ \\\ \\\ ^[\\\[0m^[\\\[31m^[\\\[1m-^[\\\[0m^[\\\[1m\\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\,d\\\$\\\$\\\'\\\  
\\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\`\\\$\\\$b.\\\  
\\\ \\\,\\\$\\\$P\\\'\\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\`\\\$\\\$\\\$.\\\  
\\\ \\\$\\\$P\\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ d\\\$\\\'\\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ ^[\\\[0m^[\\\[31m^[\\\[1m\\\,^[\\\[0m^[\\\[1m\\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\$\\\$P\\\  
\\\'\\\,\\\$\\\$P\\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\,ggs.\\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\`\\\$\\\$b\\\:\\\  
\\\ \\\$\\\$\\\;\\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ Y\\\$b._\\\ \\\ \\\ _\\\,d\\\$P\\\'\\\  
^[\\\[0m^[\\\[1m\\\ \\\`\\\$\\\$b\\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ \\\ ^[\\\[0m^[\\\[31m^[\\\[1m\\\"-.__\\\  
^[\\\[0m^[\\\[1m\\\ \\\ \\\`Y\\\$\\\$\\\ 
(...)
```

Usually `$ scp remote-host:/t <TAB><TAB>` shows me the files/folders starting with `/t` (for example `/tmp`), but now it executes the `neofetch` banner.

Is there a way to distinguish `$ ssh` from `$ scp` in `~/.ssh/rc` (to launch `neofetch` only when I `ssh` into the server, not when I `scp` into it) ?

Note : I don't want to launch neofetch each time I launch bash, nor each time I launch a login shell, so putting it in `/etc/bash.bashrc` or in `/etc/profile` is not an option. I only want to launch it after an SSH connection.

I did some research and tried a few things :

- Inspired by [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/600977/determine-whether-in-an-interactive-session-vs-non-interactive-session-ie-scp), I tried :

  `if [ -t 0 ]; then /usr/bin/neofetch; fi`

  and

  `if tty > /dev/null; then /usr/bin/neofetch; fi`

  But it's not working (`neofetch` is never launched, not even after an `$ ssh`)
- Inspired [by that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42757236/what-does-mean-in-bash), I also tried to use the `$-` environment variable to distinguish between interactive and non interactive sessions, but it doesn't work either, because `~/.ssh/rc` is parsed by dash, not by bash (and `$-` is a bash variable)

I found however a working solution (well, sort of...). It was inspired [by this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/458445/ignore-ssh-rc-file) :

- On the server, in `~/.ssh/rc`, I put :

  `if [ ! "$LC_SCP" = "yes" ]; then /usr/bin/neofetch; fi`
- On the client, I have to set an `LC_SCP` environment variable before the `$ scp` :

```
$ export LC_SCP=yes

$ scp -o SendEnv=LC_SCP remote-host:/t<TAB><TAB>
(works, doesn't launch neofetch)
```

It works, but it's cumbersomee. Isn't there a better way to distinguish between `ssh` and `scp` sessions in `~/.ssh/rc` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The environment variable `SSH_TTY` seems to be set only when `ssh`ing, not when `scp`ing.  So the following suffices (at least in my testing):

```bsh
if [ -n "$SSH_TTY" ]; then /usr/bin/neofetch; fi
```

(For what it's worth, I guessed this by looking at the output of `env | grep -i ssh`.)

Comment: perfect ! thanks !

Comment: Alas, it's possible to ssh _without_ `SSH_TTY` -- try `ssh -T`, or just `ssh host somecommand` without `-t` or `-tt` on the latter